# how to use table tr:odd td in html

Tags: html, css

When I define this CSS in HTML I found that they not show me even in Firebug but I see after edit button Firebug CSS panel [tab]

```
#tbl tr:odd td{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

well I want to make `tr`'s background color `#FFF`.

Comment: There is, ehrn... no such thing as CSS HTML. Both are separate languages on their own right.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-roadmap/), `even` and `odd` are actually arguments to the [:nth-child()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) pseudo-class, not selectors in their own right. Try:

```css
#tbl tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Of course, your browser has to support CSS3 for the above to work.