# Send pandas dataframe data as html e-mail

Tags: python, html, email, pandas

I want to send a pandas dataframe data as an HTML e-mail. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096748/pandas-dataframes-to-html-highlighting-table-rows) post I could create an html with the dataframe. Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

HEADER = '''
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
'''
FOOTER = '''
    </body>
</html>
'''

df = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.6, 2.5, 3.4,2.6,2.6,3.4,3.4,2.6,1.1,1.1,3.3], list('AAABBBBABCBDDD')]).T
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(HEADER)
    f.write(df.to_html(classes='df'))
    f.write(FOOTER)
```

Now I want to send this as a html e-mail. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python). Can not figure out how to attach the html file?

Comment: Look into ipyhon notebooks, very handy for this type of work

Comment: @Woody Pride: Not with ipython notebook :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found. This is the way it should be done.

```
filename = "test.html"
f = file(filename)
attachment = MIMEText(f.read(),'html')
msg.attach(attachment)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 13):

Pandas has a function [for this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html).

This will give the the html code for the table, after which you can embed it into an email with:

```
df = DataFrame(data)

email = " some html {df} lah lah"

email = email.format(df=df.to_html())
```