# Classes method in df.to_html()

Tags: python, css, pandas

How to use classes method in df.to_html()?

I have tried :

```
css_class = {'border-width': 'thin'}

df.to_html(index=False,classes=css_class)
```

I get an error : TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, dict found

Example data:

```
df = DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,3,5],'B':[3,4,5,6,7]})
```

I have to write this into an email. Now the output looks like:

[image]

How can I decrease the border width and make it a single lined border/thin border.

The [df.to_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) documentation doesn't give an example.

Comment: Pandas docs say: classes : str or list or tuple, you passed a dict. It applies already defined classes, so you only pass the classnames.

Comment: take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096748/pandas-dataframes-to-html-highlighting-table-rows