# Formatting Pandas DataFrame with Quantopian qgrid

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I'm attempting to use [quantopian qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) to print dataframes in iPython notebook.  Simple example based on example [notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/quantopian/qgrid/blob/master/qgrid_demo.ipynb):

```
import qgrid
qgrid.nbinstall(overwrite=True)
qgrid.set_defaults(remote_js=True, precision=2)

from pandas import Timestamp
from pandas_datareader.data import get_data_yahoo

data = get_data_yahoo(symbols='SPY',
                      start=Timestamp('2014-01-01'),     
                      end=Timestamp('2016-01-01'),
                      adjust_price=True)

qgrid.show_grid(data, grid_options={'forceFitColumns': True})
```

Other than the precision args, how do you format the column data?  It seems to be possible to pass in [grid options](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Options) like formatterFactory or defaultFormatter but unclear exactly how to use them for naive user.

Alternative approaches suggested in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760364/zebra-tables-in-ipython-notebook?lq=1) but I like the interaction the SlickGrid object provides.

Any help or suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is that most grid options are passed through `grid_options` as a dictionary, eg:

grid_options requires a dictionary, eg for setting options for a specific grid:

```
qgrid.show_grid(data,
                grid_options={'fullWidthRows': True,
                              'syncColumnCellResize': True,
                              'forceFitColumns': True,
                              'rowHeight': 40,
                              'enableColumnReorder': True,
                              'enableTextSelectionOnCells': True,
                              'editable': True})
```

Please, see details [here](http://qgrid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the float format using df.round (would be useful change the format using the column_definitions).

Anyway the slider filter isn't in line with the values in the columns, why?

```
import pandas as pd 
import qgrid
import numpy as np 
col_def = { 'B': {"Slick.Editors.Float.DefaultDecimalPlaces":2}}
np.random.seed(25) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([5, 4]), columns =["A", "B", "C", "D"]) 
df = df.round({"A":1, "B":2, "C":3, "D":4}) 
qgrid_widget = qgrid.show_grid(df, show_toolbar=True, column_definitions=col_def)
qgrid_widget
```

[image]

Comment: Using the slider is indeed oftentimes very painful. It would be great to allow users to enter min and max value of the selected range

Comment: I used also the parameter : 
precision (integer) – The number of digits of precision to display for floating-point values. If unset, we use the value of pandas.get_option(‘display.precision’).

"qgrid.show_grid(df, show_toolbar=False, column_definitions=col_def, precision=1)".

But  I can't set the individual columns, right?